# Trying adding a sound event using QMediaPlayer

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5, qmediaplayer

I made a small app using pyqt5 and I want to play a 5 seconds mp3. I read that I don't need to use a separate thread if I use Qt tools so here I am.

Why doesn't this work, is it more to it?

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtMultimedia

player = QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer()
sound = QtMultimedia.QMediaContent(QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile("c:/alarm.mp3"))
player.setMedia(sound)
player.setVolume(100)
player.play()
```

Did I read the documentation wrong?

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmediaplayer.html

```
player = new QMediaPlayer;
connect(player, SIGNAL(positionChanged(qint64)), this,   
        SLOT(positionChanged(qint64)));
player->setMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile("/Users/me/Music/coolsong.mp3"));
player->setVolume(50);
player->play();
```

Comment: You probably don't have the necessary audio codecs installed. Try it with a `.wma` file.

Comment: I tried with .wma and still noting. I'm on windows 10, it should play .wav files.

I'll  try with a different IDE, on Pycharm it runs with no errors, no feedback. Process finished with exit code 0 and that's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add `QGuiApplication`:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtMultimedia, QtGui
import sys

app = QtGui.QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
player = QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer()
sound = QtMultimedia.QMediaContent(QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile({your filename})
player.setMedia(sound)
player.setVolume(100)
player.play()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```